# sync two tables after insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert, synchronization, postgresql-9.3

I am using postgresql. I have two schemas `main` and `sec` containing only one table `datastore` with the same structure (this is only an extract)
I am trying unsucessfully to create a trigger for keep sync both tables when insert occurs in one of them. The problem is some kind of circular or recursive reference.

Can you create some example for solve this?

I am working on this, I'll post my solution later.
You can use this code as reference for creating schemas and tables

```
    CREATE SCHEMA main;
    CREATE SCHEMA sec;
    SET search_path = main, pg_catalog;
    CREATE TABLE datastore (
        fullname character varying,
        age integer
    );
    SET search_path = sec, pg_catalog;
    CREATE TABLE datastore (
        fullname character varying,
        age integer
    );
```

Comment: Um... why? Why not simply insert into the same table from both sources? Or make one table a view of the other?

Comment: No... an external system inserts data by choosing one of the tables. My interest is to replicate the data after insertion. I can't modify the current behavior. And yes... it apparently sucks

Comment: That makes no sense. System inserts into one of two tables and you want them to be the same? Why does it insert into separate ones? What was the original reason for the separation (presumably no longer needed)? I *strongly* suggest replacing one of the tables with an updatable view.

Comment: The current system _randomly_ selects one of two tables. But queries tables required, so I need they have same values. I not developed the legacy system and I can't change it for now.

Comment: Ok. So replace one of the tables with an updatable view. The code using the view won't notice.

Comment: I cant follow this approach. The task is to replicate data bidirectionally without modify the table's structure. Thanks anyway, Craig

Comment: Adding a trigger also modifies the table definition. You need the same permissions for a trigger as for creating an updatable view. You can and should use a simply updatable view instead. It will effectively make both tables into one table with a second name. No trigger requirdd.

Comment: Unless... are you trying to sync *only* inserts but not updates and deletes? Or keep different historical content but sync new changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An updatable view is the best solution and is as simple as (Postgres 9.3+):

```
drop table sec.datastore;
create view sec.datastore
as select * from main.datastore;
```

However, if you cannot do it for some inscrutable reasons, use [`pg_trigger_depth()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-info.html) function (Postgres 9.2+) to ensure that the trigger function is not executed during replication. The trigger on main.datastore may look like this:

```
create or replace function main.datastore_insert_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    insert into sec.datastore
    select new.fullname, new.age;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger datastore_insert_trigger
before insert on main.datastore
for each row when (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
execute procedure main.datastore_insert_trigger();
```

The trigger on sec.datastore should be defined analogously.

Comment: This is my accepted solution. My PG server is 9.3 so I can use it. But, how to solve the problem for servers previous to Postgres 9.2? There is an alternative to `pg_trigger_depth() = 0`?

Comment: Generally there are no straight alternatives for this function in earlier versions of postgres. Possible solutions depend on the particular case. However, in this simple case, you would not need at all `when condition` in the trigger declarations, if only the tables have primary keys (or other non-partial unique constraints).

Answer (score 0):

```
create OR REPLACE function copytosec() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
insert into sec.datastore(fullname,age) values (NEW.fullname,NEW.age); 
RETURN NEW; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger copytosectrigger after insert on public.datastore 
for each row 
execute procedure copytosec();`
```